# A div right next to another

Tags: jquery

I've got 3 divs

1 - wrapper

2 - video (I want it to be in the center of the wrapper all the time)

3 - video suggestions (I want it to be right next to the video even when you resize the video or the window)

```
<div id="videoWrapper">
    <div id="videoBlock">            
        <iframe stuff></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="videoSuggestions"></div>
</div>
```

I know that I have to find the offset of the 2nd div somehow, but my tiny human brain can't handle this. **[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/j68g9nj7/10/)**

Comment: Anyway. OP: You don't need JS/jQuery for this :)

Comment: ? Why javascript for this? This is just a few lines of CSS. Use `display:{inline-block}` to display elements side by side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CSS` Only to do this.

Apply this `CSS` to the main div, It will do all your job. Give it a shot.

```
#videoWrapper{
display: flex;
justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
align-items: center; /* align vertical */  
}
```

Comment: Flex is the best solution, so of course it's not supported in IE8, IE9 and partially in IE10 : http://caniuse.com/#search=flex. It can be an issue.

Comment: Yes @JeremyThille I agree to that. That depend's on OP what all compatibility he wants.

Answer (score 0):

Easy using just a few CSS properties : (Run it below)

```css
#videoWrapper {
  height: 400px;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#videoWrapper *{
    display : inline-block;
    vertical-align : top;
    height: 100%;
  
    
}
#videoWrapper iframe{
    border: green solid 1px;
    width : 69%;
}

#videoSuggestions {
  background-color: green;
    width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div id="videoWrapper">           
        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/<?= $videoId[1] ?>?vq=hd720&showinfo=0&rel=0&iv_load_policy=3" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><div id="videoSuggestions"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a page from **[Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed)** and use some fairly basic CSS:

```
#videoBlock {
    width: 67%;
    float: left;
}
#videoSuggestions {
    float: right;
    width: 33%;
}
.video-embed {
    padding: 0;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.video-embed iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/j68g9nj7/12/)**

Comment: That would be a few hundreds Kb to load, just to get `iframe{width:100%;}` ... Besides, you're not using Bootstrap at all in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
You dont't need to change your css.    
The errors are in jquery.
Three reasons of not working.

1st>You forgot to give '#' in $('videoblack').  
2nd>Multiple event will appear in 'bind' function(not 'on') .   
3rd>Event will on 'window' not 'document'. 

So the JQuery code will be like this

$(window).bind('load scroll resize', function () {    
    var pos = $('#videoBlock').position();    
    var width = $('#videoBlock').outerWidth();    
    $("#videoSuggestions").css({    
        position: "absolute",    
        top: (pos.top + 10) + "px",    
        left: (pos.left + width + 10) + "px"    
    }).show();   
});
```